# Scoring algorithm implementation with Django and Redis

Tags: mysql, django, redis

I use DjangoREST & MySQL as a backend for a mobiel app. I have two models, `User` and `Feed` and for any call to `api/feeds/` returns all feeds for authenticated user ordered by `created_at` parameter of feed.

However, I need to customize order of feeds for each user by simple scoring algorithm. Details of algorithm is not important but I basically need to store `score` for each `card-feed` pair in table like `UserFeedScore`.

The problem is this table will grow very fast when the number of user and feeds are increasing because there will be a row for each `user - feed` pair. Besides, for each user activity (like, comment etc) scores for each feed for that user will be updated which will exhaust MySQL db eventually.

Keeping this table in Redis seems like a proper solution but I'm not sure how I order the feeds in MySQL database by the scores calculated in Redis.

Any Redis data structure, key-value suggestions and Django query examples are appreciated.

```
class Feed(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField()
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


class UserFeedScore(models.Model)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    feed =  models.ForeignKey(Feed)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=100)
```

Comment: why do you think Redis will cope better than MySQL at storing a large number of records?

Comment: what you have modelled is a ManyToMany relation between `User` and `Feed` with a custom through table. Redis could be useful as a caching layer, but I'd build it as a basic Django/MySQL app first and only adapt it when real problems show up and it's clear where any bottleneck actually is

Comment: Storing and changing data in memory instead of disk would be faster, isn't it? Do you suggest me to cache only the query in Redis and update UserFeedScore table in MySQL anyway?

Comment: it's not clear exactly which problem you're trying to solve

Comment: Actually it's quite simple. I need to calculate score for each user-feed pair for each activity user performs. For all users, UserFeedScore table needs to be updated very frequently. Besides, when cards are fetching, it has to join this table and order cards by scores. We, of course, can do it in MySQL but it'd better to perform these updates in Redis. However, I'm not sure how I can get scores from redis and query in MySQL by those scores

Comment: do you need to store the score at all if it is changing so frequently? would it make sense to calculate the score as part of the sql query? otherwise you're going to have to load all the user's feeds from db, plus the feed-score map from Redis, and then do the actual sorting in memory in your Python code